# Join attribute by location giving bigger results QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, vector-grid

I have created a grid over South Africa, each cell being 10 km x 10 km. In addition, I have a raster layer that has been polygonized, each polygon containing a population count. The total of these population polygons equate to 53 million inhabitants

[image]

Because my computer can't handle the analysis of all the population polygons (1,5 million) I've decided to create this coarser grid, to group population estimates.

Therefore, I've joined the grid with the population polygons ("Join attributes by location"), so that each grid cell can now contain a total population, made of several pop estimates. However, when I use the tool "statistics by categories", the total sum of population inside the grid equates to 63 million...
I don't understand why there is a difference in population estimates. The sum of all the grid cells should equate to 53 million inhabitants.

Comment: Does the origin of your coarse grid align with the higher resolution grid? Is the coarse grid size an exact multiple of the fine? If not, then you have partial overlap on the join, where the population is allocated multiple times.

Comment: @Vince, I'm not sure I understand the difference, sorry...

Comment: You can see this play out by allocating uniform population in a clone of the real dataset, then plotting the resultant aggregation.

Comment: I've created the coarse grid irrespective of another, I chose to do 10km x 10km arbitrarily.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work by any chance? I'm not sure to see what you mean by allocating uniform population in a clone and plotting the resultant aggregation

Comment: Then the cost of the failure to align the grids is a 20% increase in population due to overlaps on resampling. You could prorate the allocation by using Union, but then you'd be working with a 2-3 million row feature class.

Comment: You can't use an arbitrary coarse grid to model the fine polygons without significant error. If you use a 50x50 km grid aligned to the origin of the 10km grid, you'd have roughly 1/25 of the features, and wouldn't have a many-to-many relationship from the 10k to 50k cells

Comment: Thanks for your input. So that would be your suggestion, to re create a grid of 50x50 km grid and realign it to the 10x10km one?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just an example. But it has to be a multiple of 10km, and it has to align. I work with tessellated grids on a daily basis, with up to nine levels of nesting (using your 10km example, I have 2.5,5,10,20,40,80,160,320,640 km squares all nested for multiscale modelling, summary, and display, so choosing a multiple of two is attractive, allowing infill if warranted)